# How to do multi-line spoilers properly?

Tags: support, spoilers

```
>! This is a spoiler.
>! A multi-line spoiler.
>! It works, as a spoiler, but it is not properly formatted as a multi-line spoiler.
```

> This is a spoiler.
>  A multi-line spoiler.
>  It works, as a spoiler, but it is not properly formatted as a multi-line spoiler.

---

```
>! Let's try again.

>! Maybe this will work.

>! No, it doesn't!
```

> ! Let's try again.
>
> ! Maybe this will work.
>
> ! No, it doesn't!

---

```
>!This is a workaround.
>!<p>Sadly, it requires typing lots of p tags, although the first and last lines do not require them.</p>
>!Is there a better way?
```

> This is a workaround.
>
> Sadly, it requires typing lots of p tags, although the first and last lines do not require them.
>
> Is there a better way?

Comment: You can use `<br>` tags instead or paragraphs

Comment: For me, "Is there a better way?" in the last spoiler shows up even before revealing spoilers.  Does that happen for others?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a much, much simpler way of this.

```
>! First line... <br> Second line... <br> Third line... <br> I think you understand this now `
```

> First line... 
>  Second line... 
>  Third line... 
>  I think you understand this now

`<br>` is used for creating a newline basically within a single line. In this case, the `<br>` brings all the text after it into the next line and covers the text since it is technically in the line with the spoiler tag. Consecutive `<br>` will create more and more lines. This tag is commonly used to formatting text is a specific way like a puzzle:

Do you 
 now know 
 how to make 
 multi-lined spoilers 
 without a line 
 between each line of text?

Comment: Fail. Doesn't work with numbered lists!

Answer (score 20):

You can do it in a better way:

- add two spaces in the end of the line for line-break
- add `>!` with two spaces in the new line for the line break with in spoiler.

Sample content as:

```
>! This is a spoiler.  
>!  
>! A multi-line spoiler.  
>!  
>! It works, as a spoiler, but it is not properly formatted as a multi-line spoiler.
```

> This is a spoiler.
>
>  A multi-line spoiler.
>
>  It works, as a spoiler, but it is not properly formatted as a multi-line spoiler.

Answer (score 4):

[`<p>` tags don't need closing tags in HTML5 if they're followed by other `<p>` tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p), so you can shorten things a bit:

```
>!1<p>2<p>3<p>4<p>5
```

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5

rather than

```
>!1<p>2</p><p>3</p><p>4</p>5
```

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5

As this involves less typing than even `<br>` tags, and introduces real paragraphs to boot, this is probably the best you're going to get.

Answer (score 2):

If the multi-line spoiler contains a code block (for example to format a data table), a hack to make a multiline spoiler work:

```
>!<code>line 1</code>    
>!<code>line 2</code>    
>!<code>line 3</code>
```

Produces

> `line 1`
> `line 2`
> `line 3`

Note: The four ASCII spaces after every line but the last are required.